# Is "it shall be" the same as "it is"? Specific to the context of law?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

The US constitution uses "shall be" in places where the German constitution (Grundgesetz) would use "is", and that makes sense to me, no problem so far.

But in a translation of the German law to the English language, I was surprised to see that the German "ist" was translated to "shall be".

It is the most official translation of the law, so I do not think it is for a trivial reason.

It caught my attention because the word is of essential importance in the sentence. It is the most important sentence of a constitution.

The sentences in German and the English translation are below:

> Die Würde des Menschen *ist* unantastbar.

[Grundgesetz für die Bundesrepublik Deutschland, Artikel 1](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/art_1.html)

> Human dignity *shall be* inviolable.

[Constitution of Germany, Article 1](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0019)

I see no reason not to translate "ist" to "is", but translating it to "shall be" seems to change the meaning.

It is not about demanding that human dignity should be seen as inviolable.
It is directly stating that human dignity is inviolable, as a fact. It documents a fundamental assumption.
Even is "shall be" can have the exact meaning of "is", this is not the right place for ambiguity.

So how is "shall be" the right translation of "ist" in this place?

Comment: It is a legal thought process.  Suppose human dignity is violated: the desire in the English version is to suggest that somebody must have acted contrary to the protection given by the constitution rather than that the constitution is factually incorrect.  But this is as much an issue of legal tradition as of language, with the two intertwining over history

Comment: @Henry Yes, I understand how it is used in English, and I'm totally fine with that. But it is different, and according to my intuition it can not be used in a translation like it would be  the same.

Comment: *It **shall** be* means *it **will** be* or *it **must** be* (depending on interpretation), not *it is*.